# Cross Browser Compatibility - website content not displaying correctly

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I created a website in Wordpress but I seem to be experiencing cross browser compatibility issues in Internet Explorer, most notably Internet Explorer 7 & 8

http://www.vokins.co.uk/

There is an issue with overlapping on the home page (logo and contact number) and none of the properties appear to display on property search (The page appears blank)

The year dates on the News page appear to be sitting to the right of the image rather than in the grey box

How can I rectify this to ensure consistency across all browsing platforms?

Comment: Everything seems fine to me using ie8.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your website (using the tool BrowseEmAll) in IE7, IE8 and IE9.

It works nice in IE8 and IE9 but in IE7 the overlapping is clearly visible:

[image]

I would suggest changing the margin of the element "site-title" to padding.